# PUT request works in Postman but not in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, mern

I'm building an app with MERN stack that allows to create accounts and then post or delete posts. Before the post shows up on the main page it has to be approved by user with rank of administrator. For now I'm trying to implement a feature where user can approve it's own post. It works perfect in Postman but keeps getting rejected in front end without any error messages.

Here are my backend files:

postRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const { getPosts, setPost, updatePost, deletePost } = require("../controllers/postController")
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware")

router.route("/").get(getPosts).post(protect, setPost)
router.route("/delete/:id").delete(protect, deletePost)
router.route("/update/:id").put(protect, updatePost)

module.exports = router
```

updatePost function in postController.js

```
const updatePost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)

  if (!post) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("Post not found")
  }

  if (!req.user) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error("User not found")
  }

  if (post.user.toString() !== req.user.id && req.user.admin === false) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error("User not authorized")
  }

  const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true })

  res.status(200).json(updatedPost)
})
```

And frontend files:

updatePost function in postService.js

```
const updatePost = async (postId, data, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }

  const response = await axios.put(API_URL + `update/${postId}`, data, config)

  return response.data
}
```

updatePost function in postSlice.js

```
export const updatePost = createAsyncThunk("posts/update/:id", async (postId, postData, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
    return await postService.updatePost(postId, postData, token)
  } catch (error) {
    const message = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString()
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
  }
})
```

button onClick function in my frontend component

```
onClick={() => dispatch(updatePost(post._id, { approved: true }))}
```

Comment: can you share your error

Comment: the problem is I get no errors
in Redux DevTools extension is shows up as pending and then rejected

Comment: What are you seeing in the network tab of the dev tools? If it's  401 or 403 error you may need to set `{useCredentials: true}` in axios. If's it a CORS error, you will need to enable CORS on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using cors middleware from npm package cors.

`app.use(cors())`